# How to represent navigation links with Schema.org

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I have a regular portfolio website (plain HTML) and this website includes a navigation with links to »about«, »imprint« and »contact«, so the resulting sitemap is:

```
                   index
                     |
        +-------+----+----+--------+
        |       |         |        |
      about   contact  imprint  projects
                                   |
                          +-----+--+--+-----+
                          |     |     |     |
                          A     B     C     D
```

So on the `index` (`/`) page I want to include JSON-LD like so:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebSite",
  …
  …
}
</script>
```

How can the links to "about", "contact", … be represented with Schema.org? Would:

```json
{
  …
  "@type": "WebSite",
  "links": 
  [
    {
      "@type": "WebSite",
      "@id": "https://…"
    }
  ]
}
```

be right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the `links` property, which (given your `@context`) results in the property URI `http://schema.org/links`. But this is not a valid Schema.org property, so you must not use it.

To associate the `WebPage` items with their `WebSite`, you can use the [`hasPart`](https://schema.org/hasPart)/[`isPartOf`](https://schema.org/isPartOf) property:

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebSite",
  "@id": "/#site",
  "hasPart": [

    {
      "@type": "WebPage",
      "@id": "/page-1"
    },

    {
      "@type": "WebPage",
      "@id": "/page-2"
    }

  ]
}
```

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebPage",
  "@id": "/page-1",
  "isPartOf": {
    "@type": "WebSite",
    "@id": "/#site"
  }
}
```

For the contact page, you can use the [`ContactPage`](https://schema.org/ContactPage) type. For the about page, you can use the [`AboutPage`](https://schema.org/AboutPage) type. Both are [subtypes of `WebPage`](https://schema.org/WebPage#subtypes). Schema.org doesn’t offer a subtype for each possible type of page, of course; for pages that have no specific subtype defined, you can use the broad `WebPage` type; in many cases, it’s also possible to either use [`ItemPage`](https://schema.org/ItemPage) or [`CollectionPage`](https://schema.org/CollectionPage).

If you want to represent the navigation itself, there is the [`SiteNavigationElement`](https://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement) type.

Comment: Thanks for that! Seam to be it! The `SiteNavigationElement` is not what  I am after, since that queries an existing element on the page, but i want to create the navigation based on the json data, so that would not work.

Comment: @unor Your example shows usage of both `hasPart` and `isPartOf`, creating a bidirectional connection. What if we can't define the `hasPart`, is it ok (/effective) to create unidirectional connections?

Comment: @Ethan: As these are inverse properties, it’s (semantically) sufficient to provide only one direction (the other direction can be inferred). That, however, doesn’t mean that all consumers necessarily support both ways (a "bad" consumer might be programmed in such a way that it only looks for one specific direction).